# Angular 2 select component for long length list of values

Tags: angular, user-interface, twitter-bootstrap-3, drop-down-menu, components

Looking for Angular 2 select component which could be used to easily select from hundreds of values. Actually, with ability to type in input to filter the list for selection. What are the options? Currently Bootstrap 3 is used for styling.

Answer (score 0):

Use angular's 2 way binding and make a call to the back end.

As the user types, you use a debounce to wait for them to stop typing for say 300ms, then have http make a call to your database / data store for a list that is similar to what was typed in.

For the front end, maybe consider Material Design's `md-autocomplete`: 
https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/overview

Comment: You have 2 different problems to solve here... you need a service to talk to your back end and something in the front end to style it / show it to the user. Which problem are you having issues with?

Comment: I don't want to use back-end service, i have the list already fetched in client side. I am looking for a client side solution to display the list to user to select from.